# How to search a list in Dart multi-dimensional List

Tags: list, dart, search, multidimensional-array

I've been looking for a solution to search a selected list inside a multi-dimensional list.

```
List a = [
[3, 2],
[8, 5]
];
```

to search [3,2] inside the multi-dimensional list I used this method.

```
var isContains = a.contains([3, 2]);
log('isContains: $isContains');
```

it always show the output as **false**.

but, this works for single lists like below,

```
List b = [ 3, 2, 8, 5];

var isContains = b.contains(3);
log('isContains: $isContains'); //-> OUTPUT is true
```

Why this is not work for the list a. And how we can search a list inside a multi-dimensional list?

Answer (score 1):

Some small lists like this 'a' can search for elements one by one in a simple way, and this answer gives you the opportunity to check the correct element value with the matching pointer(index), but I **don't recommend** this answer **for large multi-dimensional lists**.

A simple answer:

***check_elements.dart***

```
List a = [
  [3, 2],
  [8, 5]
];

var isContainsa = a.contains([3, 2]);
var checkEachElementAtIndex_0 = a[0][0] == 3 && a[0][1] == 2;
var checkEachElementAtIndex_1 = a[1][0] == 8 && a[1][1] == 5;

void main(List<String> args) {
  print('Contains 3 & 2: $checkEachElementAtIndex_0');
  print('Contains 8 & 5: $checkEachElementAtIndex_1');
}

// Output
// Contains 3 & 2: true
// Contains 8 & 5: true
```